# Property type 'Int' does not match that of the 'wrappedValue' property of its wrapper type 'EnvironmentObject'

Tags: environment-variables, swiftui

I'm trying to use an @EnvironmentObject to pass data to my SwiftUI view:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var myInt: Int // ❌ Property type 'Int' does not match that of the 'wrappedValue' property of its wrapper type 'EnvironmentObject'

    var body: some View {
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```

```
func constructView() {
    let myInt = 1
    MyView()
        .environmentObject(myInt)
}
```

The line with @EnvironmentObject had a compiler error (listed above).

How do I use `@EnvironmentObject` with an `Int`?

---

**Update:** One thought was that `@EnvironmentObject` can only be used with classes that conform to `ObservableObject`, so I tried switching to `@Environment` which now that part compiled, but produced a different error:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @Environment var myInt: Int

    var body: some View {
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```

```
func constructView() {
    let myInt = 1
    MyView() // ❌ Missing argument for parameter 'myInt' in call
        .environment(\.myInt, myInt)
}
```

Now when I attempt to construct it, it complains that `myInt` isn't set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use the environment system, you need to provide a key to access it. You can't use an unregistered key (which is what your error is). First, create an `EnvironmentKey`:

```swift
struct MyIntEnvironmentKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue = 0
}
```

Next, create a key path to set/get your environment value:

```swift
extension EnvironmentValues {
    var myInt: Int {
        get { self[MyIntEnvironmentKey.self] }
        set { self[MyIntEnvironmentKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Now, you can set it in your parent View:

```swift
MyView().environment(\.myInt, myInt)
```

And crucially, you need to reference the key in the view in which you want to reference it:

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @Environment(\.myInt) private var myInt: Int

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(self.myInt)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

`@EnvironmentObject` can **only** be used with a `class`. `Int` is actually a `struct`.

If you did want to try to share that `Int` between `View`s, you could wrap the value in a class:

```
class SharedInt: ObservableObject {
    @Published var myInt = 1
}
```

Also, it should look more like this inside `SceneDelegate.swift`:

```
let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(SharedInt())

if let windowScene = /* ... */
```

Or in SwiftUI lifecycle's `...App.swift`:

```
WindowGroup {
    ContentView()
        .environmentObject(SharedInt())
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought I could save time by creating a `class EnvironmentObjectWrapper<T>: ObservableObject` that wraps the value, but the SwiftUI environment seems to disambiguate on the type of object, not on any sort of key name, so such a wrapper would easily conflict with other values. It appears you're better off creating a different Environment object for each class (e.g. `class MyViewEnvironment: ObservableObject`)

Comment: @Senseful I don't know if it is possible like you said, but either way I wouldn't create a wrapper. It is much better to be explicit about what you are trying to do - no generics should be needed. Simpler code is almost always better :)